# react JS i18n locales

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, i18next, react-i18next

I'm using react-i18next in my reactJS app

is something like this possible:

```
i18n
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        // we init with resources
        resources: {
            en: {en},
            de: {
                application: {
                    name: 'Dashbord DE',
                }
            }
        },
```

Nesting/grouping the locales

and print them like this:

```
t('application.dashboard')
```

Problem is that not the translation is printet ... my key application.dashboard is printed ...

Thanks.

update:

```
de: {
   application: {
      foo: "adsad",
      name: {
        firstname: 'max'
      },
   }
 }
```

This is not working:

```
t('application:name.firstname')
```

Comment: You need to add some more details: what is 'en' object, what does it contain

Comment: just the same then in de

Comment: so you should call t('application.name') instead of t('application.dashboard'). Your translations do not contain 'application.dashboard' key.

Comment: yes ofcourse thats not the problem ... was a copy paste problem. 

problem is that I can not access the firestname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t('application:name')` will do the trick. application acts as namespace (loaded filename) and needs per default be separated with `:`. While all other nestings are separated with `.`, eg.:

```
de: {
       application: {
          name: {
            firstname: 'max'
          },
       }
    }
```

`t('application:name.firstname'); // -> max`

Comment: problem solved I had to define the separator 

`keySeparator: '.'`